# Eigenvalue multiplication endomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

When considering the multplication endomorphism 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
[\times z]_{K/Q}: & \:\: K \rightarrow K \\
& \:\: x \:\mapsto xz
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
for $Q$ a field and $K$ a finite $Q$-algebra, we get the eigenvalues $z_1,...z_n$ which are the roots of $P_{K/Q,car,z}(X) = \text{det}(X.\text{Id}_K-[\times z])$.

Now the course notes that I'm working with quickly mention that the eigenvalues of $P([\times z]_{K/Q})$ are $P(z_1),...,P(z_n)$ for any polynomial $P\in Q[X]$ and I'm really not convinced.

Comment: Rather hard to guess what you mean by $[\mathrm x z]$, especially since '$\mathrm x$' never appears in your conclusion. Could you by any means be talking of the operation of multiplying by $z\in K$, viewed as $Q$-linear operation on $K$? In that case I would certainly prefer the typography $[\times z]$, and even then put in an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first thing to understand here is that the result of substituting $[\times z]_{K/Q}$ for $X$ into a polynomial $P$, which result your write as $P([\times z]_{K/Q})$ (I would personally prefer the more explicit $P[X:=[\times z]_{K/Q}]$) is equal to to operation of multiplication by $P(z)$ (more explicitly by $P[X:=z]$), so in formula
$$
  P([\times z]_{K/Q})=[\times P(z)]_{K/Q}.
$$
To see this, there is really not much more than to observe that $([\times z]_{K/Q})^k(y)=z^ky$ for any $y\in K$ and any exponent$~k$, and then use linearity to pass from these monomials to general polynomials.

Now over a suitable extension of $Q$, one can find a basis such that $[\times z]_{K/Q}$ is represented on it by an upper triangular matrix with diagonal entries $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ (if they are all distinct one can even get a diagonal matrix, which makes intuition a bit simpler). On that basis $P([\times z]_{K/Q})$ is upper triangular matrix with diagonal entries $P(z_1),\ldots,P(z_n)$, and the result follows.

(I realise that I did not even use what is said in the first paragraph, but I'll let it since it seems relevant anyway.)